# ssh-add add all private keys in .ssh directory

Tags: ssh, grep, find, xargs, ssh-agent

In my day-to-day, I need to *ssh* to various machines, all of which I have a different private key for.

When I start a new shell session - only my default id_rsa is added to the ssh key chain - I have been running

> ssh-add ~/.ssh/*

However this also trys to, and fails, when adding things like *~/.ssh/config*

Using `find` / `grep`, how can I go about *only* adding valid private key files?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to add all these keys? If you specify the `IdentityFile` for each host inside your `~/.ssh/config` file, ssh will use that file when you try to connect.

Comment: Using Amazon AWS, my host IP address are ephemeral, and are constantly changing ( test stacks ). I can not rely on a config file to always be correct. Each layer of the stack has different user permissions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Slightly convoluted, but:

```
for possiblekey in ${HOME}/.ssh/id_*; do
    if grep -q PRIVATE "$possiblekey"; then
        ssh-add "$possiblekey"
    fi
done
```

You can also add *all* of your keys to your `~/.ssh/config` each in their own `IdentityFile` directive *outside* of a `Host` directive:

```
# Global SSH configurations here will be applied to all hosts
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_project1
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_someotherkey

Host somespecifichost.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_specifichostonlykey
```

The latter, honestly-better, method has the added perk of not suddenly picking up a new key that you've added without you explicitly adding it to the "keyring" as it were.

Comment: ohhh, good call. I did not actually know that `IdentifyFile` definitions could exist outside of a `Host`.

Comment: Unfortunately this can prevent you from connecting to a server if you have many keys, claiming `Too many authentication failures` as it tries each key one by one for all servers, and some disconnect after a certain number of incorrect keys are tried.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need `find`, you can just use a recursive grep using the `l` flag to send only matching filenames:

`grep -slR "PRIVATE" ~/.ssh/ | xargs ssh-add`

Answer (score 4):

I have come up with the following command to do this:

```
find ~/.ssh/ -type f -exec grep -l "PRIVATE" {} \; | xargs ssh-add &> /dev/null
```

This will  `find` all files in the *.ssh* directory that contain `PRIVATE`, passing the name / path of the private key file to `ssh-add`.

Comment: This is the best way out of these answers if you have multiple keys with the same passphrase, as you will only have to enter it once.

Answer (score 0):

This uses regex to match all files beginning with `id_` and not ending with and dot-suffix, like `.pub`.

```
find ~/.ssh -type f -regextype egrep -regex '.*/id_[^.]+$' | xargs ssh-add
```

The problem with using a for loop, like in the accepted answer, is that you will keep on needing to enter the passphrase even when the same one is used for all keys.